# Why isn't my halogen floor lamp working with new bulb and new dimmer switch?

Tags: troubleshooting, lamp

I replaced the bulb and the dimmer switch. There is 120V between the connections when switched on. It varies between 115V on low and 122V on high. The bulb has continuity. I also measured the voltage across the bulb when in place and switched on and it was about 0.4V. I also rocked the bulb back and forth to make a better connection. This was the dimmer switch I installed: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00002NAH8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00002NAH8)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "... the voltage across the bulb ... was about 0.4V." That's definitely wrong.

Comment: *What* dimmer switch? Could you please link the one you used, there are many different types.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That sounds like what would happen after mixing up phase with ground?

Comment: Have you tried taking the dimmer switch out of the setup to see if it works without it?

Comment: @DigitalNinja Hook the bulb straight to power? Is that allowed? Will it burn out?

Comment: Yes it's allowed and no it won't burn out.

Comment: @Chloe It is safe. I just suspected the dimmer being the point of failure. Could it be that the dimmer was off? From the Amazon link, there is an "off click position" on the knob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jms was right. The ribbed wire was mixed with the smooth wire at the bulb end. I switched them but it still didn't work. The voltage when on was about 0.7V. I tested with a straight connection like @DigitalNinja said and it did light up! So the brand new switch is bad!

[image: Wire Mixup Ground-Positive/Ribbed-Smooth]
[image: Low voltage after fixing connections]
[image: Bad switch straight from the wall]